# Inconsistent values of ARM PMU cycles counter

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, arm64, intel-pmu

I'm trying to measure performance of my code in linux kernel with pmu.
First of all I want to test pmu therefore created simple loop of couple operations in kernel. I placed it under spin lock with disabled interrupts so my test code can't be preempted. Then I printed cycle counter to check how much CPU cycles this loop takes. But I see very different values at each print: 100, 500, 1000, 200, ...
My question is: why I see so different values every time?
PS: in countrary to cycle counter, pmu's instruction counter is stable and I see same values every time.
I also tried to use arm timer but it also showing different values similar to pmu's cycle counter.
Here is how I use ARM timer to measure performance:

```
unsigned long long ticks_start, ticks_end;
int i = 0, j;
unsigned long flags;

spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
while (i++ < 100) {
   j = 0;
   asm volatile("mrs %0, CNTPCT_EL0" : "=r" (ticks_start)); 
   while (j++ < 10000) {
      asm volatile ("nop");
   }
   asm volatile("mrs %0, CNTPCT_EL0" : "=r" (ticks_end));
   printk("ticks %d are: %llu\n", i, ticks_end - ticks_start);
}
spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
```

and output on real device are (cortex A-57):

```
...
ticks 31 are: 2287
ticks 32 are: 2287
ticks 33 are: 2287
ticks 34 are: 1984
ticks 35 are: 457
ticks 36 are: 1604
ticks 37 are: 2287
...
```

Comment: Please provide exact code how and what are yo measuring

Comment: why would you expect it to be the same every time?

Comment: @Alex Hoppus I provided ARM timer code snippet.

Comment: @old_timer But I don't understand why such huge difference, for ex. 100 then 500... What cause this? It executed in atomic context on same CPU core, but I see different values every time

Comment: you running it out of dram or on chip sram?  you have other cores active?  you have the caches disabled or enabled?  how are you timing it?

Comment: what does the disassembly show?  try real assembly so you can control what is going on.  does the disassembly of your code as written show that it is building the code you expected?  I would assume j is in a register and would hope that the variables are saved to memory after the loop, but if before the loop then there is a wide open hole for execution time to vary.

Comment: @scopichmu you should provide assembly

Answer (score 4):

For using things like timers and PMU on Arm, you should be inserting an `isb` instruction before the read of the PMU register.  The processor is allowed by the architecture to speculatively read the register early, or late since it is not dependent on your inner loop of `nops`.

So try this:

```
asm volatile("isb; mrs %0, CNTPCT_EL0" : "=r" (ticks_end));
```

The `isb` will flush the pipeline before letting the `mrs` instruction proceed.  It is possible the CPU is also thermally throttling, but that should not affect your measurements using the cycle-counter, but it would if you were reading the generic timer to measure time.

Comment: hi. The ISB is a keypoint. But I wonder wether it can produce so large delta. As far I understand, speculatively reading CNTPCT_EL0 an't succesful until the last loop since it is not on the target branch, am I right?